# Diferenciar alto y largo de figuras en Findcontours python openCV

Tags: python, ubuntu

Estoy haciendo un codigo para identificar vegetacion y medirla linealmente.
Ya logro generar la mascara binaria de vegetacion y suelo. 
ahora viene el proceso de identificar las figuras(vegetacion), logro perfectamente identificarlas y medirlas, pero con un error en la medición, mide menos de lo que debería medir.
En el codigo uso la funcion 'Box' para identificar los 4 puntos extremos de cada figura, después hago lo mismo para encontrar los puntos medios de los 4 lados. El objetivo es medir el LARGO, y al momento de representar con un circulo los puntos medios para calcular el largo, a veces los pone como el ancho y no el largo. ¿Como puedo hacer para que identifique solo los largo y no se confunda con los anchos?
En el codigo represento con un circulo los 4 puntos medios, pero para probar si los puntos medios del extremo superior e inferior estan bien identificados, dejé comentado los otros dos. Y aqui veo el error, que me pone en algunos el ancho en vez del alto, como muestra en la imagen.

El otro error es la medición, en las figuras que detecta BIEN el largo, no mide exactamente bien. En la imagen se ve la representacion del largo en pixeles para cada figura, y por ejemplo la seguna de izquierda a derecha deberia medir 127 pixeles y mide 74.

A que se deben estos errores?

Codigo( le ingreso una mask , la ruta de la imagen original y su nombre):

```
ruta = 'Mosaicos para Ploteo/30/'
filename = 'Mosaico Cuartel 30 - 35x35 cm.tif'

orig = cv2.imread(ruta+filename)
mask_hsv= cv2.cvtColor(orig,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lw_range = np.array([0,0,0]) #oscuros
up_range = np.array([180,203,180]) #claros
mask=cv2.inRange(mask_hsv,lw_range,up_range)

def medir_y_dibujar(mask,ruta_orig,filename):
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
total_m = 0
orig = cv2.imread(str(ruta_orig+filename))

for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) < 5:
        continue
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = np.array(box, dtype="int")
    box = perspective.order_points(box)
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    #for (x, y) in box:
    #   cv2.circle(orig, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = box # (top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left)
    (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)  #PUNTO MEDIO ENTRE TOPLEFT Y TOPRIGHT
    (blbrX, blbrY) = midpoint(bl, br)  #PUNTO MEDIO ENTRE BOTTOMLEFT Y BOTTOMRIGHT

    (tlblX, tlblY) = midpoint(tl, bl) #PUNTO MEDIO ENTRE TOPLEFT Y BOTTOMLEFT
    (trbrX, trbrY) = midpoint(tr, br) #PUNTO MEDIO ENTRE TOPRIGHT Y BOTTOMRIGHT
    ekis , yy = tl 
    # draw the midpoints on the image
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(orig, (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)


    # draw lines between the midpoints
    #cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),
    #   (255, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.line(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),
        (255, 30, 100), 2)

    #medir distancias

    distance = math.sqrt(((tltrX-tlblX)**2)+((tltrY-tlblY)**2))

    cv2.putText(orig, "{:.1f}p".format(distance),(int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)

return orig
```

Yo pienso en discriminar el largo con el ancho con un IF y quedarme con el mas largo. pero pienso que debe haber otra solucion. 
El otro error es la medicion erronea de la LINEA generada entre dos puntos.
[image: Resultado]

SOLUCIONADO

```
    distance_1 = math.sqrt(((tltrX-blbrX)**2)+((tltrY-blbrY)**2))
    distance_2 = math.sqrt(((tlblX-trbrX)**2)+((tlblY-trbrY)**2))
    if(distance_1 >= distance_2 ):

        cv2.line(orig, (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), (int(blbrX), int(blbrY)),
            (255, 0, 0), 2)
        m_lineal = distance_1 * cm_p_pixel
    else:
        cv2.line(orig, (int(tlblX), int(tlblY)), (int(trbrX), int(trbrY)),
            (255, 0, 0), 2)
        m_lineal = distance_2 * cm_p_pixel
```

Calculé las distancias con pitágoras e hice la condicional para quedarme siempre con el mas largo (que será el LARGO y no el ancho)

Comment: Lo solucione!!!!

Comment: Si encontraste una solución, lo ideal es que la agregues como respuesta, así puede servirle a alguien en el futuro que tenga tu mismo problema. Saludos

Comment: ok, ahi lo añadí ! :)